# How to find employee's experience from two dates?

Tags: c#

I would like to be able to find find the difference between an employee's join date and today.  Here is my C# code:

```
    DateTime JoinDate = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text );
    DateTime TodayData = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan servicePeriod = TodayData - JoinDate;
    Response .Write ( servicePeriod);
```

It gives an incorrect answer:

```
1.11:52:52.6477489
```

The format of TextBox1.Text is MM/dd/yyyy.

I want the output in Years, Months and Days.

Comment: What does `TextBox1.Text` look like?

Comment: Its value is date and its format is MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: Is the answer wrong, or is it not the format you want?

Comment: @ Amit it's answer is not format what is i want

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it to:

```
TimeSpan servicePeriod = TodayData.Subrtact(JoinDate);
```